# Watir-Webdriver "Element is not currently visible" error after closing popup windows

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'm using the latest versions of watir-webdriver and firefox to visit a website, close any popup windows that appear, and then click a link in the original window. 
But I'm running into this error message 
**Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)** after switching back to the original window and then clicking the link. This code works fine when it doesn't encounter any popup windows.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'


browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

browser.goto "http://www.artbracket.com"

#wait for page to load
browser.wait_until { browser.body.exists? }

#close any popup windows
while browser.windows.size > 1
    browser.windows.each_with_index do |w, index|
        unless index==0 then w.close end        
    end
end

#switch back to first window
browser.windows.first.use

if browser.link(:href => /opensocial/i).exists? then browser.link(:href => /opensocial/i).click end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For what it is worth, your script seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tested it in Windows 7 and it worked so I guess it's just a bug with Ubuntu.

Comment: I've had issues when closing windows before I've selected another persisting one. Try browser.windows.first.use before you close other windows.